# Is there an API to get active chef-client run details?

Tags: chef-infra

The API documentation provides an endpoint to get all the runs on a node that was completed (either successfully or error-ed out). However, I have a requirement to check if there is an active chef-client run that is executing. How can I get this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thers is no such api which i am aware of.

i can offer your to write a custom boolean node attribute at the beginning and the end of the chef-client run (you might want to look at [chef handlers](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#event-types)) to reflect that, then you can use [knife search](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html) and query for the custom node attribute. for instance

```
$ knife search node "is_running:false"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.